# Create refreshable scope variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying create variable in HTML but ngInit don't refresh it.
Here's code:

```
        <div class="table-days" data-ng-repeat="day in currentWeek">
            <div class="table-responsive day-table-margin one-day-row">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover day-table-row">
                    <tbody data-ng-init="menu = (order | menuDinnersId : kid : day)">
                        <tr data-custom-href="/selectMenu/{{day.getDate()}}/{{day.getMonth() + 1}}/{{day.getFullYear()}}/{{kid}}">
                            <td class="col-md-4 menu-table-row">
                                {{(dinners | filter : {id : menu.first} : true)[0].name}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-4 menu-table-row">
                                {{(dinners | filter : {id : menu.second} : true)[0].name}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-4 menu-table-row row-with-button">
                                {{(dinners | filter : {id : menu.extra} : true)[0].name}}
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle show-additional btn-day-remove"
                                        data-ng-if="menu != undefined"
                                        data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); openModal(kid, menu)">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need `$scope.menu` leter (as you can see). Have you any idea how to do this? I hope my post is clear enoght.

**EDIT**

I've got this line:

```
<tbody data-ng-init="menu = (order | menuDinnersId : kid : day)">
```

and I'm using `menu` leter, eg. here:

```
<td class="col-md-4 menu-table-row">
    {{(dinners | filter : {id : menu.first} : true)[0].name}}
</td>
```

But than when I change `order` variable menu doesn't update. I completely understand that it shouldn't, but I'm looking for alternative. So question is: how to create refreshable menu variable. It can be in controller, but I also don't have idea how can I do that. As you can see I'm using `menu` in many place so I don't to reevaluate it over and over again. I want to do this once in every loop iteration.

Comment: Not clear at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: if this is a ternary, you missed the `?`

Comment: [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) --> `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`

Comment: where is the code that changes the menu?

Comment: @HarishR there isn't angular use one or two way binding and change value every time when model change, but obliviously it's not working with ng-init and I'm looking for alternative for ng-init, which change my menu automatic

Comment: do it in controller, remove ng-init do , `$scope.$watch('order', function(){ $scope.menu = order[0] //or whatever}`